# Mock DayJs default function along with its chained methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocking, jestjs, dayjs

I'm trying to mock **dayjs()** default function with specific date & time and also wants to mock its nested methods i.e .**utc()** & .**add()**

This is what I've tried so far:

abc.ts:

```
getEarliestDate() {
    const {
        minHour,
        maxHour
    } = operatingHours;
    const earliestDateTime = dayjs().add(sla + 1, 'minute');
    const earliestDateTimeUTC = earliestDateTime.utc();

    return dayjs().add(121, 'minute').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
}
```

abc.test.ts:

```
import { abc } from '../../src/common/serviceFactory';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

jest.mock('dayjs', () =>
  jest.fn((...args) => jest.requireActual('dayjs')(args.filter((arg) => arg).length > 0 ? args : '2020-08-12')),
);

jest.mock('dayjs', () => ({
  default: jest.requireActual('dayjs')(`2020-08-18 12:00:00`),
  extend: jest.fn(),
  utc: jest.fn((...args) => {
    const dayjs = jest.requireActual('dayjs');
    dayjs.extend(jest.requireActual('dayjs/plugin/utc'));

    return dayjs.utc(args.filter((arg) => arg).length > 0 ? args : '12:00:00').startOf('day');
  }),
  add: jest.requireActual('dayjs')(`2020-08-18 12:00:00`),
}));

describe('getEarliestDate Function', () => {
  it('should return earliest date response', () => {
    const earliestDate = abc.getEarliestDate();
    expect(earliestDate).toMatch(dayjs().add(121, 'minute').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
  });
```

But getting this:     `TypeError: dayjs_1.default is not a function`

Any help/suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: Can you us the usage code.

Answer (score 6):

MockDate works great for this, no intense mocking code required.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate

```
import MockDate from 'mockdate'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'

MockDate.set('2000-11-22')
console.log(dayjs.format())

// >>> 2000-11-22T00:00:00Z
```

Remember to clear the mock after your test with:
`MockDate.reset();`

Comment: This solution is amazing. Worked effortlessly. Big thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For basics operations with dayjs this code works:

```
jest.mock('dayjs', () => jest.fn((...args) => jest.requireActual('dayjs')(args.filter((arg) => arg).length > 0 ? args : '2020-08-12')),);
```

When '2020-08-12' is the date you want to mock.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the `default` function of mocked module is supposed to be the function instead of the result of return of `dayjs()`. Try as following would work then:

```js
jest.mock('dayjs', () => ({
  default: jest.fn((...args) => {
    const yourDay = jest.requireActual('dayjs')(args.filter((arg) => arg).length > 0 ? args : '2020-08-11');
    // Mock add function
    yourDay.add = jest.fn(() => jest.requireActual('dayjs')(`2020-08-10 12:00:00`));
    // more mock
    return yourDay;
  })
}));
```

Also remove the other mock since it would replace:

```
jest.mock('dayjs', () => ({
  default: jest.requireActual('dayjs')(`2020-08-18 12:00:00`),
  extend: jest.fn(),
  // ...
}));
```

***Another solution, you can change and keep your first mock stay the same:***

```
jest.mock('dayjs', () =>
  jest.fn((...args) => jest.requireActual('dayjs')(args.filter((arg) => arg).length > 0 ? args : '2020-08-12')),
);
```

The only thing you would do is to enable the option `esModuleInterop` in your `tsconfig.json` since this option will add `default` function for you automatically:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response.. I also need to mock the other functions i.e .utc() & .add(), How can I do that?

Comment: I left more idea for you in the answer again

Comment: I encountered this and tbh, don't really understand the example. I think this answer would be improved some if there was a little more clarification provided. I upvoted because the effort is strong. Thanks

Comment: DId you guys come up with a solution? I really need one.

Comment: For me I finally got it working with just `jest.mock('dayjs', () => ({ default: jest.requireActual('dayjs') }));`